# Dilemma regarding switching time of processes and kernel

Tags: process, operating-system, kernel

*T1* is the time taken to switch from (user process) process p1 to p2 while *T2* is time taken to switch from process p1 to kernel process - Now which will be more T1 or T2. For me it should be T1, my logic is, when the CPU is allocated to process p2 by removing p1 the kernel will have to (first take control in its hands &) remove the PCB of p1 and load PCB of p2. While in case of p1 to kernel, it just have to give control to kernel. Am I right/Wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you are right as transition from process to kernel will happen in response to some specific event such as system call. Transition from user mode to kernel mode with in same process even though does not require context switch (kernel code is run in same process context) but a lot of other things, such as table look ups and retrieving values passed from user mode, checking validity of parameters, also happen in the transition along with saving registers. I think same or more functionality is performed when interrupt occurs.